# how to use $ref to refer json file in jsonschema

Tags: json, python-3.x

suggest me how to use the remote json file in the input jsonschema . Below are the two files which i was using got exception as unknown url

first.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "ReferenceTosecondSchema": {
            "$ref": "second.json#/definitions/ExternalType"
        }
    }
}
```

second.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "ExternalType": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "src": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "src"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use definitions from external files in JSON Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388284/how-to-use-definitions-from-external-files-in-json-schema)

Comment: improve code formatting